# combo problem help

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: Danielle has $2023^3$ boxes in which she can place non-negative integers. Each box is assigned a unique ordered triple $(i, j, k)$ with $i, j, k \in \{1, 2, 3, · · · , 2023\}$. In the box with ordered triple $(1, 1, 1)$, Danielle places $a_0$. Then, for a box labeled $(a, b, c)$, she places the smallest non-negative integer that has not been placed in any of $(a_0, b, c)$ for $0 \le a_0 < a$, $(a, b_0, c)$ for $0 \le b_0 < b$, or $(a, b, c_0)$ for $0 \le c_0 < c$. Find the number Danielle places in the box labeled $(2023, 203, 20)$.

I thought about it and the number should be around $2022\times 202\times 19$.
The answer is 1855 and I do not know why.

Comment: Doesn’t the answer depend on the number placed in $(1,1,1)$?

Comment: If $k$ is placed in the $(1,1,1)$ then the answer seems to be $2022+202+19+k$.

Comment: Have you copied the question word for word? Or is it paraphrased?